# Variable not defined error in Classic ASP (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4'

Variable is undefined: 'product_id'

/Vital/form/products.asp, line 64

I am using option explicit and I have defined the variable as

```
Dim product_id

product_id=Request.Form("product_id")
```

Is this a problem with IIS or sql server 2003? Actually its working fine when i access my sql server 2008 database from localhost. But the problem comes when my client uploads the asp file to web server and try to access mysql 2003 database.

Comment: Based on your code I have no idea how SQL even comes into the picture. product_id should be fine as long as the form page is actually passing it.

Comment: is this actually line 64? Even if `product_id` was omitted in a post request, you wouldn't get this error.

Comment: Post real code, not scrapes. Post code around line 64 in "products.asp" and the code around the `Dim` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, I have to guess and I guess you define the variable inside a function, for example:

```
Function Foo
    Dim product_id

   '......
End Function
```

Then having the line `product_id=Request.Form("product_id")` outside the function will indeed result in error, as it's only local to that function.

It got nothing to do with IIS or database - pure VBScript issue.